# Custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout animation

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewlayout

I've got a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout animation that staggers views in from the right with insertions and out to the left with deletions. It does it by setting a CABasicAnimation on the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and applying this to the cell layer.

[image: Screen Grab]

[CollectionViewAnimations Project on GitHub](https://github.com/devedup/CollectionViewAnimations)

The default alpha is 0 and its fading out my cells and ending my custom animation early. If I change the alpha to 1 then i don't see my animation at all. I set it at 0.5 and I get a bit of both.... it's weird. You'd have to run my project to see what I mean.

[AnimatingFlowLayout.swift](https://github.com/devedup/CollectionViewAnimations/blob/master/CollectionAnimationTest/AnimatingFlowLayout.swift)

For some reason, I can't seem to completely remove the default alpha on the attributes in finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` which already animates the changes you set in  `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(_:)`, so if you add the `CABasicAnimation` you're adding animation to animation that's already gonna happen. If you drop the animation from your `CellLayoutAttributes` and just set the `transform3D` of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` it's gonna do what you want (except the animation `beginTime` and `fillMode`). This piece of code works well for me:

```
override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    let attributes: CellLayoutAttributes = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath) as! CellLayoutAttributes
    // Default is 0, if I set it to 1.0 you don't see anything happen..'
    attributes.alpha = 1
    let endX = -CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView!.frame)
    var endTransform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(endX, 0, 0)
    attributes.transform3D = endTransform

    return attributes
}
```

Comment: To get the animation's `beginTime` effect, you can add your cells one-by-one like they proposed [here](http://aplus.rs/2014/how-to-animate-in-uicollectionview-items/). Also `UICollectionView` uses default duration to animate cell's appearance. And looks like there is no way to change it in a proper/non-hacky way.

Comment: "except the animation beginTime and fillMode" - that's the whole point of this animation... the staggered effect.

Comment: point being you're adding animation to already ongoing animation

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, for a similar problem:

```
import UIKit

class NoFadeFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = super.initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attrs?.alpha = 1.0
        return attrs
    }

    override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at itemIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attrs = super.finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem(at: itemIndexPath)
        attrs?.alpha = 1.0
        return attrs
    }

}
```

You said you couldn't get the default alpha to go away in this method, but it worked when I tried it on tvOS 11.